# Recalculating Land Size from RestAPI service in AGOL

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api

I am putting together a map in the web based AGOL map creator that would show population density using a [restAPI](https://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/arcgis/rest/services/TIGERweb/Tracts_Blocks/MapServer/12) from the US Census. The field that contains the area is called AREALAND and is calculated out in square feet and I am interested in converting this into square miles. I have tried to add a calculated field in AGO, but the table options don't allow me to create a field since it's an read only file. I could calculate out the density in the pop-up, but I can't get it to show the density on the map. Is there another way to create a virtual field?

***UPDATE***
So I found the query [link](https://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/arcgis/rest/services/TIGERweb/Tracts_Blocks/MapServer/11/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=arealand%2C%20hu100%2C%20pop100&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&f=html) at the bottom of the page and I am assuming that this is where I could do a simple query (AREALAND / 27878400) , but I am not sure where this calculation needs to be done or the formatting of the query (VBA JS?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that can be accomplished with a custom field.
simply open up the webmap with the rest attached and go to change style > choose an attribute to show > custom > use arcade to create a custom calculation.

In this case I was looking to calculate the population density by square mile, so I just had to put the population / (area ft/ 27878400)

```
$feature.POP100 / ($feature.AREALAND / 27878400)
```